# SVN Ignore for all Repository

Tags: svn, ignore

is it possible to set the svn:ignore (or something similar) for my repositories (instead of the working copy?)

there is some kind of configuration file i can modify to get this working?
hope someone can help me,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `global-ignore` is that it's a per user basis. Each user must add that to their Subversion configuration.

What you really need is a pre-commit hook. I have [one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can do exactly what you want: Ban particular files types from ever being committed anywhere in your repository.

This is a Perl script, but it requires no optional parameters (unless you want to use the LDAP functionality to create user groups).

Comment: if you can postit would be awesome :)

Comment: There's a link to it in my post above. If you missed it, it's https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook

Comment: Thank you david, this was very usefull! Could you tell me if there is a way to make the commit go ahead if there are errors?
Example:
All the files in /cache/ should not be commited.. if there are any, then simply skip them and commit the other files outside that folder.

is it possible?

Comment: In Subversion, commits are all or nothing, so there's no way to allow a _partial commit_. However, you teach the developers _DA RULES_, and how to setup their `.subversion` configuration file to avoid getting hit by your pre-commit hook. After their third rejected commit, they'll setup their `.subversion` configuration file.

Comment: i wrote you an email (found the mail address in the github repo) another question, so that we don't spam here (tell me if you got it)

Answer (score 1):

There is subversion config file:

http://svn.gnu.org.ua/svnbook/svn.advanced.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config

Where you can set ignores.

```
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
```

Comment: this is going to work even if i try to commit those kind of file (they will simply get ignored, and the commit will proceed as nothing happens?)

Comment: @Easly - no. these files are ignored only in status and wide-add command: `svn add` without filename